# Android: Using Person with NotificationCompat

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-push-notification

I want to use `Android`'s [`Person`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Person) class to create a sender of a `notification` so the user image is displayed in `MessagingStyle` notifications in `Android P`.

However, the [`NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle) class doesn't support using the `Person` class, it only seems to be supported by [`Notification.MessagingStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.MessagingStyle) (see the addMessage method).

Is there any way to use the `Person` class with `NotificationCompat`?

This is what I want to do:

```
NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle msgStyle = NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.extractMessagingStyleFromNotification(notification); 

Person.Builder builder = new Person.Builder().setName(name).setIcon(icon);

msgStyle.addMessage(message, System.currentTimeMillis(), builder.build());
```

In case there isn't, I need to use the `NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle` class because I'm using the method "extractMessagingStyleFromNotification" to keep the existing messages in the notification, that way I only need to add the new one. Is there any way to achieve the same using `Notification.MessagingStyle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) instead of Android Support Library, since the latter is no longer updated.